# Enabling interrupts on 8052 causes lock-up

Tags: loops, microcontroller, interrupt, interrupt-handling, 8051

The problem I have currently is that ever since I enabled interrupts, the program is stuck in an endless loop. If I disable the interrupts then the program executes normally.

I even made sure that I protected the registers (variables) in the functions by pushing them onto the stack and popping them off upon exit of the function, and that did not help.

I even took the step to even replace the function names with only iret (to exit from interrupt), and I still face the same problem.

The only way for me to solve the problem right now is to disable the interrupts by not executing `mov TCON,#50h`. This makes me think that the interrupt vector addresses published on the internet are not correct, and that in reality, screwed-up code is being executed instead.

My microcontroller I'm using is AT89S52.

Am I off with my vector addressing here? I need some advice because the code I currently use below is currently not working when timer interrupts are enabled.

```c
org 000h
;entry point when program first runs
ljmp sysinit ;seems to execute
sjmp $
org 00Bh
;Timer 0 interrupt executes every 65536 machine cycles even if timer 1 interrupt executes
ljmp crit
sjmp $
org 01Bh
;Timer 1 interrupt executes every 256 machine cycles
ljmp processkey
sjmp $
org 030h
start:
;rest of program goes here.

sysinit:
mov TL0,#0h
mov TH0,#0h
mov TH1,#0h
mov TL1,#0h
mov PSW,#0h
mov R0,#7Fh
;make all ram addresses 0h to 7Fh contain value 0
sysreset:
CLR A
mov @R0,A
djnz R0,sysreset
mov T2CON,#0h  ;8052 register
mov AUXR,#0h   ;8052 register
mov AUXR1,#0h  ;8052 register
mov PCON,#80h  ;Make baud divisor=192
mov TMOD,#21h  ;Timer1=0-255,Timer2=0-65535
mov IP,#02h    ;priority to timer 0
mov TCON,#50h  ;timers on
mov SP,#050h   ;stack=50h
mov IE,#8Ah    ;ints enabled
ljmp start
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the interrupt service routines actually clear the interrupts? If not, the core will continuously try to serve them hence the apparent lockup.

Check out the [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc1919.pdf) pg. 17:

> Timer 2 interrupt is generated by the logical OR of bits TF2 and EXF2 in register T2CON. Nei-
>   ther of these flags is cleared by hardware when the service routine is vectored to. In fact, the 
>   service routine may have to determine whether it was TF2 or EXF2 that generated the interrupt, 
>   and that bit will have to be cleared in software.

So your interrupt will keep firing if the flags aren't reset.

Why are you writing your code in assembly anyway? Surely, for this functionality you could use plain C instead.

Comment: Assembler is what I have plus it provides more control. I have considered your shown fragment, and R0 means contents of address 0. since DJNZ doesn't continue when R0 reaches zero, I give the value 0 to addresses 1 to 7Fh in the loop, and upon exit, the address zero is 0. I read that the timer interrupt flags are automatically cleared when the interrupt executes unless the literature at 8052.com is incorrect?

Comment: I also tried converting my interrupt handler routine to only have the RETI command and that's it and the program still produced screwed-up results. Somehow I think atmel isn't providing information that it needs to provide.

Comment: Sure the interrupts are temporarily disabled when jumping into the isr. However, if you don't clear the cause of the interrupt, it will be issued anew. I updated my answer to include a quote from the datasheet.

Comment: Thanks but I haven't gone for timer 2 interrupts.

Comment: I just tried replacing my interrupt code so that the timer values are reset and the overflow flags are cleared and I still get no success. Is there a different vector address the chip executes timer interrupts at? I filled my code with nops for 32 bytes starting with the third byte then executed my interrupt after and that didnt help. I also have ea/vpp line tied low so it can access on-chip EEPROM.